# What is the difference between buildSchema and makeExecutableSchema

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js

What is the difference between `buildSchema` from the `graphql` package and `makeExecutableSchema` from the `graphql-tools` package.

Comment: I think that `buildSchema` didn't exist at first, so they're the same but just `buildSchema` got added later

Answer (score 23):

Apart from the fact that they are from two different packages since `buildSchema` is from the [official graphql-js package](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) and `makeExecutableSchema` is from [Apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools), they also do a slightly different things.

`buildSchema` builds a schema object from schema language. It takes just one big string of Type definitions as an argument.

`makeExecutableSchema` combines schema and resolvers to make executable schema. It's part of a [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools) package that makes it easier to use the schema language while also writing resolvers. So you define types and resolvers and pass them to `makeExecutableSchema`. You can pass an array of Schema definitions to it so that way you could merge multiple schemas together, modularize it.

See [Apollo docs for graphql-tools](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/index.html) to see their suggested way of building GraphQL servers.

Comment: But I don't have to pass resolvers, so what would be the differences in this case

Comment: You have to pass resolvers to `makeExecutableSchema`. They are required. That is one way of building a GraphQL server when you are using `graphql-tools`. You don' have to do it that way so you can use `buildSchema` instead and pass your resolvers as an option to your GraphQL endpoint.